# Kendo UI - custom grid filter: checkbox doesn't work on each click

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

[UPDATE]

After I did as in:
http://dojo.telerik.com/aqIXa
 when I click for example ProductName filter, and then select and deselect all items, go to other fields example Unit Price,click select and deselect all I turnback to Product Name field, and in filter is now:

[image]

You can see that Select All combobox is created once more and it will continue to create after I repeat the steps. Does anyone has the Idea why is it happend?

I'm currently working in Kendo and try to make custom grid filter for each column.
I used this example:

http://dojo.telerik.com/iwAWU

inside initCheckboxFilter function I added, which created checkbox for select all.

```
var selectAllCheckbox= $("<div><input type='checkbox' id='checkAll' checked/> Select All</div>").insertBefore(".k-filter-help-text");
```

and outside that function I implemeted:

```
function clickMe(){
   $("#checkAll").click(function () {
    if ($("#checkAll").is(':checked')) {
        $(".book").prop("checked", true);
    } else {
        $(".book").prop("checked", false);
    }
});
}
```

(.book is class for template inside:

```
 var element = $("<div class='checkbox-container'></div>").insertAfter(helpTextElement).kendoListView({
          dataSource: checkboxesDataSource,
          template: "<div><input type='checkbox' class='colDefFilter'  value='#:" + field + "#' checked />#:" + field + "#</div>",
        });
```

)

I also added UnitPrice and UnitInStock fields:

```
function onFilterMenuInit(e) {
        debugger;
        if (e.field == "ProductName" || "UnitPrice" || "UnitInStock") {
          initCheckboxFilter.call(this, e);

        }
      }
```

This looks like:

[image]

The first time I click Select All  checkbox on some column filter, it check and uncheck all items and it works fine. When I try to do it on other column, the event is not trigger. Does anyone has idea what is wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using id for check all checkbox that's why jquery always select check-box from first drop-down (Product)

you need to use checkAll as class not id then change your clickMe() function like this and it will work :

```
function clickMe(){
       $(".checkAll").click(function () {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
           $(this).closest('.k-filter-menu').find(".book").prop("checked", true);
        } else {
            $(this).closest('.k-filter-menu').find(".book").prop("checked", false);
        }
    });
    }
```

Here is working example http://dojo.telerik.com/aqIXa

**Edit :**

the way you are using to add Select all checkbox should be like this

```
var selectAllCheckbox= $("<div><input type='checkbox' class='checkAll' checked/> Select All</div>").insertBefore(e.container.find(".k-filter-help-text"));
```

insted of this

```
var selectAllCheckbox= $("<div><input type='checkbox' id='checkAll' checked/> Select All</div>").insertBefore(".k-filter-help-text");
```

otherwise it will add multiple Select All check box for previously initialized filter-dropdowns.

Here is updated demo :http://dojo.telerik.com/aqIXa/4

Comment: Cool, If it works for you could you please accept my answer :)

Comment: I have just one question: after I click select/and deselect All on Product Name field, close filter, repeat same on other field (for example Unit In Stock) and than again click Product Name filter, I have 2 Select all comboboxes! (the other select all combo box is now created below list of item and above 'Is equal to filter'), do you know why is this happening? Thanks!

Comment: It happening because the function initCheckboxFilter() is called each time when a new filter initialize and you use  k-filter-help-text class to append your check all checkbox. Now what happens here is that jquery search for  k-filter-help-text class and it add checkbox for all matching element. So you need to change your selector like this selectAllCheckbox= $("<div><input type='checkbox' class='checkAll' checked/> Select All</div>").insertBefore(e.container.find(".k-filter-help-text"));

Comment: You are genius! :D I'm new to this and your explanations are great. Once again, thanks! :)

Comment: glad to help you :)

Comment: Hello! In this http://dojo.telerik.com/aqIXa/4 example all other filters are not available?